# Changing the color of the Rainbow Worm

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I am using Mike Bostock’s Rainbow Worm as a part of my project.
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4165404

I am trying to change the color of the worm, as it will represent wind speed in the project. The coloring is described by this function:

```
var path = svg.selectAll("path")
.data(quad(points))
.enter().append("path")
.style("fill", function(d) { return d3.hsl(z(d[1].value), 1, .5); })
.style("stroke", "#000");
```

If I replace function(d) with a "color", worm will be single colored.
How can i make worms parts be colored as red->white->red->white->red->white and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the index (the second parameter) and a [remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()):

```
.style("fill", function(d,i) { return i%2 ? "red" : "white" })
```

This is what this snippet does:

The second parameter, here named `i`, is the *index* of each datum, going from 0 to `data.length - 1`.

Then, using the remainder operator...

```
i % 2
```

... we will get a series of zeros and ones:

```
010101010101010101...
```

As in JavaScript (and all languages I'm aware of) 0 is falsy, the tertiary operator will return "white" and "red" alternately.

Here is the bl.ocks: http://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/fd5c1e6644d742e43c737ff4a17f96ff